# Using Exp:resso Store for workshop registrations

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce

A client is looking for a lightweight e-commerce system to sell a couple digital products, as well as workshop registrations.

Exp:resso seems like a good fit, but I'm not sure how to capture each registrant's details. Would I use the 9 custom fields available to the checkout tag? Would I roll my own?

The flow essentially would be: select a workshop (product), select a quantify (number of registrants), enter their names and titles, checkout, send a receipt.

I'm aware of moreEvents but I'd like to keep this as simple and native to EE as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the custom order fields, or you can store the name with the product (make it a text modifier so people enter it when they add the item to their cart.

The advantage of using product modifiers is that the customer would be able to add multiple "tickets" to their cart, each under a different name. If you use custom order fields then there is only one set of fields per order.